# Can't solve complicated second order differential equation (Poisson-Boltzmann equation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there anyone able to solve this second order differential equation? It is the Poisson-Boltzmann equation (found in the field of electrostatics) solved on cylindrical coordinates just on the radial direction.
$$
(\varphi'+r\cdot\varphi'')=A\cdot e^{−(B\cdotφ+C)}
$$
where $\varphi$ is the variable I want to solve the problem for, the derivatives of $\varphi$ are with respect to $r$, while $A,B,C$ are constants.

I have been around it for a long time and can't solve it. What I had tried was to do a variable change by setting a new variable called z for instance which is equal to the exponential term, but I arrive nowhere.

All the help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Hello @Miguel_s, welcome to MSE! Can you please add in the question (not in the comments) what you have tried and where exactly you got stuck? It also it useful to tell us where you encountered this equation. That way, it is easier for others to give you a 'spot-on' answer. Also, on this forum we use MathJax to typeset mathematical formulas. It is highly recommended that you learn it and use it here. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I have just edited the question. Concerning the MathJax, I will have a look on it and take that into account when setting equations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r=e^s$ ,

Then $s=\ln r$

$\dfrac{d\varphi}{dr}=\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dr}=\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}=e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}$

$\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{dr^2}=\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}\right)=\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}\right)\dfrac{ds}{dr}=\left(e^{-s}\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}-e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}\right)e^{-s}=e^{-2s}\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}-e^{-2s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}$

$\therefore e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}+e^{-s}\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}-e^{-s}\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}=Ae^{−(B\varphi+C)}$

$e^{-s}\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}=Ae^{−(B\varphi+C)}$

$\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}=Ae^{s−B\varphi-C}$

Let $u=s−B\varphi-C$ ,

Then $\varphi=\dfrac{s−u-C}{B}$

$\dfrac{d\varphi}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{B}-\dfrac{1}{B}\dfrac{du}{ds}$

$\dfrac{d^2\varphi}{ds^2}=-\dfrac{1}{B}\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{B}\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}=Ae^u$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}=-ABe^u$

$u=\ln\dfrac{2c_1\text{sech}^2\sqrt{c_1(s+c_2)^2}}{AB}$

$s−B\varphi-C=\ln\dfrac{2c_1\text{sech}^2\sqrt{c_1(s+c_2)^2}}{AB}$

$\varphi=\dfrac{s-C}{B}−\dfrac{1}{B}\ln\dfrac{2c_1\text{sech}^2\sqrt{c_1(s+c_2)^2}}{AB}$

$\varphi=\dfrac{\ln r-C}{B}−\dfrac{1}{B}\ln\dfrac{2c_1\text{sech}^2\sqrt{c_1(\ln r+c_2)^2}}{AB}$